# Having DNS issue with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, dns

I had a DNS problem recently. My internet connection stopped abruptly the other day for an unknown reason. Someone told me to change manually the file `/etc/resolv.conf`  with the ip address 208.67.222.222:

```
# Generated by expressvpn
search expressvpn
nameserver 10.44.0.7
```

It worked fine, but it was just a temporary solution. Each time a put a VPN or restart the computer, I have to change de nameserver with the ip 208.67.222.222. Is there an alternative solution? Otherwise, can I make this solution permanent?

Comment: Why are you not letting ExpressVPN be the default name server? I use that product and I always let their DNS do the look ups.

Comment: Not sure to understand. It is not my intention to change the name server, but this is what works for me. I don't even understand why the address 10.44.0.7 doesn't work while 208.67.222.222 works. I am not an expert in networking and DNS.

Comment: OpenDNS Home https://www.dnsperf.com/dns-resolver/opendns: OpenDNS Home is a public DNS service, and it is available for free. ... Its primary DNS Server's IP address is 208.67. 222.222, and its secondary Server's IP address is 208.67.

Comment: 10.44.0.7 should be the DNS of your ISP.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I had never played with my internet connection before. I was doing an homework for school and band. Out of nowhere, the connection stopped. I panicked a bit and after 2 hours I solved my problem. But it is just a patch for the moment. I would like to find a permanent solution.

Comment: An ISP DNS can fail once in a while stuff happens usually the failure does not last to long. The same can  happen with the free DNS you changed to. In the expressvpn config there is option to use their DNS I would suggest you have that on.